# how to get session in databse by user_id and set that for another user in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-session

I have saved my session in database, Now I want to get the shopping cart session of special user by `user_id` after scanning a qrcode and set that shopping cart session for `Auth::user()`.

as you know, the session table in databse have these fields:
`id`,   `user_id`,  `ip_address`,   `user_agent`,   `payload`,  `last_activity`

how to access the `$cart = session()->get('cart');` by `user_id` ?

Comment: Do you use any cart packages? Something like, `$user = User::findOrFail($user_id); $cart = $user->get('cart');` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the session_driver in config\session.php from the file to a database like:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

and created the sessions table

```
php artisan session:table
```

and also change your .env file `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

After that DB session will work and you can check in our DB and you can manage it accordingly.